Site-To-Site IPSec between StrongSwan and zyxel usg100
We bought USG flex 100 into our office and we added it to the nebula.
Now, we need to setup site-to-site tunnel into our datacenter. On nebula site we have network 10.5.1.0/24 and in datacenter we have subnets 10.1.4.0/24 and 10.8.0.0/23. I need to have both networks from datacenter connected to the nebula device in our office, but nebula can't write two subnets to the remote networks.
In datacenter I have kerio router and Debian server, which has installed strongswan, so I can connect nebula to one of them. It doesn't matter, which of them it will be…
Do you know, how to do it?
Thanks
